# Should I share project via NuGet or just send a zip file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget, nuget-package

I'm working on a project(ASP.NET MVC) and a client(who is also a developer) asked me if I can send him a zip file of the project.  I'm curious if I can [utilize NuGet to do that](http://docs.nuget.org/)? I know it is used to add projects for open software use but how about private sharing? Can I create a NuGet package and send it to him?

Or, since I want to share the entire solution, would it be just easier to zip the folder and send it to him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nuget.org** is used to host **Libraries**, not Projects

We name **Library** to external DLL's (also called Assemblies) that we need to add to our project, the same as `.jar`'s are in Java World.